# Contesting closure of a question

Tags: support, closed-questions

If stack exchange is a democratic web site, is there a way to contest to reopen a closed question, or is it common to get "bulldozed" by the administrator. In other words, is there a way I can contest a decision to close a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post here on Meta giving us the specific question and why you think it should be reopened, and if enough people agree, it will be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability to vote to close a question, then you also have the ability to vote to reopen a question.

If the question was closed.  My suggestion is to figure out why the question was closed.  If the question can be improved so that it meets the guidelines for being on-topic, then I would suggest improving the question, voting to reopen, and leaving a comment on the question stating why you think the question should be reopened.

I've seen this happen on [Project Management SE](http://pm.stackexchange.com) where a closed question was quickly cleaned up and reopened.  This actually leads to a more interesting point:  If a question can be improved, it should probably not be closed.